# Would Plutarch be considered a historian by modern standards?

Tags: roman-empire, historiography, biography

I've been reading his "Parallel Lives" and it's clear part of the goal is to tell how some fundamental characters lived, so people can know their stories, but the other part is to set and reinforce a moral standard of roman days. Discipline, self-devotion, humbleness, courage and so on.
It's like he's trying to update Homer and Hesiod myths, but backed by tought research (considering their standards).

What impressed me is that I've been watching documentaries (from the 80's or 90's probably) about those days and they don't differ much from Plutarch's books.

So, can we consider him a historian in the present time?

Comment: What is "tought" research?

Comment: Does the definition of a historian change over time?

Comment: anyone who has done accurate peer reviewed and accepted research on historical topics can be considered a historian.

Comment: Would you consider Plutarch's lives to be peer reviewed?

Comment: "It must be borne in mind that my design is not to write histories, but lives." - [Life of Alexander](http://classics.mit.edu/Plutarch/alexandr.html), Plutarch.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be "Would Plutarch be considered a biographer by modern standards?" To which the answer is an obvious yes.

Comment: @TylerDurden I think that's the most accurate description. Perhaps you should consider expanding your comment to an answer?

Comment: Martin, did you mean tough? or thought?

Comment: @TylerDurden, that seems to make sense. My point is, can we really trust in what he wrote as a biographer or has modern research shown that facts were different from what he'd written?

Comment: If historians were banned from the profession if they wrote stuff that were proved wrong later, there'd be no historians at all.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Plutarch would not be considered a historian from the modern standard of academic or professional history.  Plutarch lacked the equivalent of a modern University's research degree in history.  Plutarch did not work in a context of post 19th century historiography.  In particular Plutarch's writing of "history" for moral instruction is greatly frowned upon amongst modern historians.

Can we trust Plutarch's opinions and what he writes?  No.  Can we trust *any* text?  *No*.  Who should we trust most about Plutarch's text, if we are not an expert historian on Plutarch and his era?  Modern historians whose opinions have been subject to peer review.

Comment: Why should we trust modern historians, when, as you say, their writings have been filtered through the set of prejudices that are known as "post 19th century historiography"?

Comment: I would say none of past "developer" could be called a "scientist", maybe except mathematicians like Euclide (as mathematics is very universal), but no cognitive science. The [scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) dates [medieval times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_history_of_scientific_method#13th_through_17th_centuries)

Comment: @jamesqf there's a lot of professional credit for historians in detecting attempts to mislead or falsify on the part of other historians.  Historiography as a social process of making ideas is quite doubtful of the ideas it produces.

Comment: Many excellent historians don't hold Uni degrees in that subject.  Not a criteria at all.

Comment: Feel free to provide your own answer.  Mine's based on professional practice as I experience it.

Comment: @Oldcat The vast knowledge of the late 1770's western europe doesn't give any historian, wether how vast and good his knowledge on that topic or how excellent on that topic he is, superiority on Bronze Age mediterranean trade knowldege over a, let's say, bronze age eastern mediterranean cultures Phd that just got it ( the doctorship).

Comment: Or, more precisely, my vast and excellent knowledge in android development doesn't mean i know a single line of Erlang, nor can i discuss anything about it with a Erlang Developer. We're both developers, but we're focused on different topics.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that the writing of Biographies is inherently historical, then yes, Plutarch could be viewed as a Historian by "Modern standards".  However, if you believe that the writing of Biographies is independent and distinct from traditional or conventional historical analysis/historiography, then no, Plutarch is not a Historian by "Modern standards".